# Audio Metering levels with AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, avplayer

Is there a way to have the audio metering levels from the AVPlayer class?

I know that AVAudioPlayer does that, but it doesn't play streamed http .m3u8 urls , like AVPlayer does.

Comment: Did you have any success?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/akhilcb/ACBAVPlayerExtension

Comment: Looks great! I'll check it out.

Comment: Has anybody found the solution to it. @adev : I tried using above ACBAVPlayerExtension but its throwing error "ACBAVPlayerExtension[329:43663] failed to setup processor".

Comment: @SJ3040, It used to work fine for me. I am not sure what changed. It wont work for streaming audio since Apple restricts it. I am not sure if you were using for that.

Comment: @adev Oh, I wanted to use it for streaming audio (to play an url with .m4a) :( So there is no way to make it for streaming audio? Except for stream the audio manually

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, specifically, if they privatized what you're looking for, but I do know the various high-level classes are usually just the tops of the pyramid for the lower level AV items. In any case, I do have good news...

Remember an AVPlayer uses an AVPlayerItem. The AVPlayerItem has assets (and an AVAudioMix). The AVAssets have the properties for modifying audio and video.

Unfortunately, the properties indicate they are "suggestions", not absolutes, but try this:

preferredVolume

If you reference the docs, AVPlayer->AVPlayerItem->AVAsset and voila. It might be what you're after.

Hope it's enough

Comment: I'll  check that out and will let you know the results :-)

Comment: Did you have any success Winston?

Comment: That's from the docs: "The preferred volume of the audible media data of the movie; often but not always 1.0.". If I understand it right, the topic starter needs to get a sound power changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There is  a fork of audioStream  [link](https://github.com/idevsoftware/AudioStreamer) ,does what you want.

I had try avplayer for days ,but the end shows it can't. Likely i find the  audioStream fork version.This code is 4 years old ，but still works good at ios7（change the demo  target from ios3 to ios7）.

Comment: I've been to that example before, but it doesn't handle .m3u8 stream format as I need. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently found this [GitHub project called SCWaveformView](https://github.com/rFlex/SCWaveformView) that helped me a lot, and I hope someone else out there could benefit from it as well.

**Edit:**
Actually the extension suggested by dev in the comments is quite nice, and you can find it [here](https://github.com/akhilcb/ACBAVPlayerExtension), the `ACBAVPlayerExtension`.

Comment: Are you able to share your final solution with us?

Comment: No, never got a final solution for this, using AVPlayer Class.